# equal? predicate for lists

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

> **Exercise 2.54**
>
> Two lists are said to
>   be `equal?` if they contain equal
>   elements arranged in the same order.
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> (equal? '(this is a list) '(this is a list))
> ```
>
> is true, but
>
> ```
> (equal? '(this is a list) '(this (is a) list))
> ```
>
> is false. To be more precise, we can
>   define `equal?` recursively in terms of
>   the basic `eq?` equality of symbols by
>   saying that `a` and `b` are `equal?` if they
>   are both symbols and the symbols are
>   `eq?`, or if they are both lists such
>   that `(car a)` is `equal?` to `(car b)` and
>   `(cdr a)` is `equal?` to `(cdr b)`. Using
>   this idea, implement `equal?` as a
>   procedure.

I wrote the following:

```
(define (equal? a b)
  (or (and (and (symbol? a) (symbol? b)) (eq? a b))
      (and (null? a) (null? b))
      (and (and (and (not (null? a)) 
                     (list? a))
                (and (not (null? b))
                     (list? b)))
           (and (equal? (car a) (car b))
                (equal? (cdr a) (cdr b))))))
```

Can this be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `and` operation is associative, one could write:

```
(and (and (symbol? a) (symbol? b)) (eq? a b))
```

as:

```
(and (symbol? a) (symbol? b) (eq? a b))
```

Similarly:

```
(and (and (and (not (null? a)) 
               (list? a))
          (and (not (null? b))
               (list? b)))
     (and (equal? (car a) (car b))
          (equal? (cdr a) (cdr b))))
```

is equivalent to:

```
(and (not (null? a))
     (not (null? b))
     (list? a)
     (list? b)
     (equal? (car a) (car b))
     (equal? (cdr a) (cdr b)))
```

One could extend the definition of `equal?` to work with both lists and pairs simply by changing the test `list?` to `pair?`.  This also obviates the need to test for non-nullity within the same `and` clause.

Using the above guidelines, one may write a shorter definition thus:

```
(define (equal? a b)
  (or (and (symbol? a) (symbol? b) (eq? a b))
      (and (null? a) (null? b))
      (and (pair? a)
           (pair? b)
           (equal? (car a) (car b))
           (equal? (cdr a) (cdr b)))))
```

Conceptually, one may think of null, symbol, and pair as types.  To test for equality of two objects, one needs to check that their types are the same and then test for equality in that type.

Thus, to test for equality, if we see that objects are symbols, test for `eq?`; if we see that objects are null, no further test is necessary so they're equal; if we see that objects are pairs, test for equality of car and cdr.

This insight allows one to extend the definition of `equal?` to other types (hash tables, vectors, etc.) if one should choose to do so in the future.

Comment: That's associativity, not commutativity.